# How do I prove this for a borel sigma algebra on R?

Tags: probability, borel-sets

[image]

I know that I much show each side is a subset of the other, but i am not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you see that the left hand side is a subset of the right hand side ?

Comment: no, since i see the left interval includes infinity while the the right excludes infinity

Comment: Then try reading the Hints I wrote below, they should help

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(i) $(-\infty,y)= \underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\cup}[-n,y)$

(ii) $[x,y)= (-\infty,y) \setminus \Big(\underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\cup}(-\infty,x-\frac{1}{n})\Big) $